# Obtener dato desde SharedPreferences

Tags: android, android-studio

tengo 2 string almacenados con sharedpreferences en una clase login, dentro del onClick de un Button.

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString("rut",loginText.toString());
            editor.putString("pass",passwordText.toString());
            editor.apply();
```

Estos valores los recibo en otra Activity invocando el método creado obtenerValor(String keyPref).

```
public byte[] obtenerValor(String keyPref) {


    SharedPreferences _prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);


    //String valorPassPreferences = _prefs.getString(keyPref, "jjj");

    return _prefs.getString(keyPref.toString(), "JJJ").getBytes();

    }
```

Necesito cifrar uno de estos datos posterior a un onAuthenticationSucceeded de la clase FingerPrint que se encuentra en otra Activity. CipherInit es el método que realiza el cifrado.

fingerPrintActivity está instanciada anteriormente.

```
 @Override
public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(
        FingerprintManager.AuthenticationResult result) {

    try {

        fingerPrintActivity.cipherInit();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Toast.makeText(appContext,
            "Authentication succeeded.",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}



public boolean cipherInit() throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    try {

        plainBytes = obtenerValor("pass");
        Log.i(TAG, "cipherInit: valor plainBytes: " + plainBytes);
        // Generate the key first
        KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        keyGen.init(128);  // Key size
        Key key = keyGen.generateKey();

        // Create Cipher instance and initialize it to encrytion mode
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");  // Transformation of the algorithm
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] cipherBytes = cipher.doFinal(plainBytes);

        final String encryptedString = new String(cipherBytes, "UTF-8");
        Log.i(TAG, "EncryptString: encryptedString " + encryptedString);

        // Reinitialize the Cipher to decryption mode
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, cipher.getParameters());
        byte[] plainBytesDecrypted = cipher.doFinal(cipherBytes);

        final String unencryptedString = new String(plainBytesDecrypted, "UTF-8");
        Log.i(TAG, "decryptString: desencript " + unencryptedString);

        //decryptString();
        return true;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException |
            NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get Cipher", e);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}
```

}

El error se produce cuando desde cipherInit() llamo a obtenerValor("pass") pasándole como parámetro el dato que requiero cifrar. Al entrar a este metodo, y al realizar

```
   SharedPreferences _prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
```

me entrega el error `E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: ---, PID: 6783
                                                                          java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
                                                                              at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:132)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.getLocalClassName(Activity.java:5559)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.getPreferences(Activity.java:5592)
                                                                              at --.ui.fingerprint.FingerPrintActivity.obtenerValor(FingerPrintActivity.java:109)
                                                                              at --.fingerprint.FingerPrintActivity.cipherInit(FingerPrintActivity.java:123)
                                                                              at --fingerprint.FingerprintUiHelper.onAuthenticationSucceeded(FingerprintUiHelper.java:113)
                                                                              at android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager$MyHandler.sendAuthenticatedSucceeded(FingerprintManager.java:894)
                                                                              at android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager$MyHandler.handleMessage(FingerprintManager.java:842)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)`

Pero al realizar el llamado al método obtenerValor() desde el onCreate de la app no tengo problemas y me trae correctamente el dato. Qué puede estar ocurriendo?

log con getsharedpreferences.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: ---, PID: 32581
                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
                                                                            at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:164)
                                                                            at .factoring.ui.fingerprint.FingerPrintActivity.obtenerValor(FingerPrintActivity.java:110)
                                                                            at .factoring.ui.fingerprint.FingerPrintActivity.cipherInit(FingerPrintActivity.java:124)
                                                                            at .factoring.ui.fingerprint.FingerprintUiHelper.onAuthenticationSucceeded(FingerprintUiHelper.java:114)
                                                                            at android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager$MyHandler.sendAuthenticatedSucceeded(FingerprintManager.java:894)
                                                                            at android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager$MyHandler.handleMessage(FingerprintManager.java:842)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
```

********Agrego Código Completo de FingerPrintActivity********

```
package .factoring.ui.fingerprint;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.KeyguardManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;

import .factoring.R;

import static android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity;


public class FingerPrintActivity extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = FingerPrintActivity.class.getSimpleName();


private Cipher cipher;
private Key key;
private FingerprintManager.CryptoObject cryptoObject;
private FingerprintManager fingerprintManager;
private KeyguardManager keyguardManager;
private Context context;
private SharedPreferences prefs;


private String DEFAULT_KEY_NAME = "default_key_name";

final String PREFS_NAME = "my_name_preferences";
private byte[] plainBytes;
List<byte[]> arrPlainBytes;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   // setContentView(R.layout.fingerprint_dialog_container);
   // LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
   //  View frame = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fingerprint_dialog_container, null);
    ValidaHuella();
    keyguardManager =
            (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    fingerprintManager =
            (FingerprintManager) getSystemService(FINGERPRINT_SERVICE);


    if (!keyguardManager.isKeyguardSecure()) {

        Toast.makeText(this,
                   "La seguridad de la pantalla de bloqueo no está habilitada en Configuración",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "El permiso de autenticación de huellas digitales no está habilitado",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return;
    }

    if (!fingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints()) {

        // This happens when no fingerprints are registered.
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Debes registrar por lo menos una huella en la Configuración de seguridad",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    cryptoObject = new FingerprintManager.CryptoObject(cipher);
    FingerprintUiHelper helper = new FingerprintUiHelper(this);
    helper.fingerprintHandler(fingerprintManager, cryptoObject);

    obtenerValor("rut");
    obtenerValor("pass");

}

public byte[] obtenerValor(String keyPref) {

    Log.i(TAG, "obtenerValor keyPref: "+keyPref);

    SharedPreferences _prefs = getSharedPreferences("myPref",MODE_PRIVATE);
    Log.i(TAG, "obtenerValor valor prefs " + _prefs);
    // String valorPassPreferences = prefs.getResources().getString(R.string.pass_Shared);
    //String valorPassPreferences = _prefs.getString(keyPref, "jjj");


    Log.i(TAG, "obtenerValor: valor " +  _prefs.getString(keyPref, "jjj").getBytes());
    return _prefs.getString(keyPref.toString(), "JJJ").getBytes();

}

public boolean cipherInit() throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    try {

        plainBytes = obtenerValor("pass");
        Log.i(TAG, "cipherInit: valor plainBytes: " + plainBytes);
        // Generate the key first
        KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        keyGen.init(128);  // Key size
        Key key = keyGen.generateKey();

        // Create Cipher instance and initialize it to encrytion mode
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");  // Transformation of the algorithm
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] cipherBytes = cipher.doFinal(plainBytes);

        final String encryptedString = new String(cipherBytes, "UTF-8");
        Log.i(TAG, "EncryptString: encryptedString " + encryptedString);

        // Reinitialize the Cipher to decryption mode
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, cipher.getParameters());
        byte[] plainBytesDecrypted = cipher.doFinal(cipherBytes);

        final String unencryptedString = new String(plainBytesDecrypted, "UTF-8");
        Log.i(TAG, "decryptString: desencript " + unencryptedString);

        //decryptString();
        return true;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException |
            NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get Cipher", e);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}

private void ValidaHuella (){



        FingerprintAuthenticationDialogFragment fragment
                = new FingerprintAuthenticationDialogFragment();

        fragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "Dialog Fragment TAG");

      /*  fragment.setCryptoObject(new FingerprintManager.CryptoObject(mCipher));
        boolean useFingerprintPreference = mSharedPreferences
                .getBoolean(getString(R.string.use_fingerprint_to_authenticate_key),
                        true);
        if (useFingerprintPreference) {
            fragment.setStage(
                    FingerprintAuthenticationDialogFragment.Stage.FINGERPRINT);
        } else {
            fragment.setStage(
                    FingerprintAuthenticationDialogFragment.Stage.PASSWORD);
        }
        fragment.show(getFragmentManager(), DIALOG_FRAGMENT_TAG);
    } else {

        FingerprintAuthenticationDialogFragment fragment
                = new FingerprintAuthenticationDialogFragment();
        fragment.setCryptoObject(new FingerprintManager.CryptoObject(mCipher));
        fragment.setStage(
                FingerprintAuthenticationDialogFragment.Stage.NEW_FINGERPRINT_ENROLLED);
        fragment.show(getFragmentManager(), DIALOG_FRAGMENT_TAG);
    }
```

*/
    }

}

Comment: Rodrigo, agrega mas datos que entrega el LogCat al ocurrir el error, busca un "Caused by", @Rodrigo

Comment: muchas gracias por contestar, agregué el log completo en mi pregunta original.

Comment: Cual es la linea  109 y 123  de FingerPrintActivity @Rodrigo ?

Comment: @Elenasys la 109 es SharedPreferences _prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);

y la 123 plainBytes = obtenerValor("pass");

Comment: Rodrigo, ambas actividades están en un mismo package? Por otro lado te recomiendo utilizar `getSharedPreferences(APP_ID, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)` donde **APP_ID** es el nombre de la preferences. De este modo podes especificar una preferences dedicada para tu aplicación.

Comment: Agregué una respuesta, tu clase no extiende de Activity ese es el problema

Comment: El OP esta usando getPreferences()  y no getSharedPreferences() por lo tanto no es necesario usar una id de preferencia.

Comment: Segun la documentacion (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) La diferencia es la siguiente:  getSharedPreferences() - Use this if you need multiple preferences files identified by name, which you specify with the first parameter.

getPreferences() - Use this if you need only one preferences file for your Activity. Because this will be the only preferences file for your Activity, you don't supply a name.

Comment: gracias @LeandroMaguna, la Activity Login se encuentra en otro package. Igualmente habia probado con getSharedPreferences, y tambipen me figuraba un error. Ahora mi duda es, se puede colocar cualquier valor en APP_ID?

Comment: @Rodrigo  **APP_ID** segun la documentacion es lo siguiente:
     
`String: Desired preferences file. If a preferences file by this name does not exist, it will be created when you retrieve an editor (SharedPreferences.edit()) and then commit changes (Editor.commit()).` 

En sintesis si, podes ponerle cualquier valor que sea representativo y le permita identificar la preferences a tu app.

Comment: @LeandroMaguna modifiqué la pregunta agregando el log con el error, ahora con getsharedpreferences.

En el código solo modifiqué esto:
   SharedPreferences _prefs = getSharedPreferences("myPref",MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: @LeandroMaguna usando getSharedPreferences el primer argumento no es un id de aplicación es un nombre de preferencia.

Comment: @Rodrigo Probaste usando `this.getSharedPreferences("myPref",MODE_PRIVATE);` o `getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("myPref",MODE_PRIVATE)` ? Por la excepción es un tema de contexto. Por otro lado hay alguna razón por la cual la aplicación utilice **Activity** como clase base de las actividades y no **AppCompatActivity**?

Comment: @LeandroMaguna, si lo había probado con this, creo que no con getApplicationContext, voy a revisar. Efectívamente es Activity la clase base, AppCompatActivity fue solo una prueba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mas alla del uso de `getPreferences()` y `getSharedPreferences()` el problema residia en la llamada al metodo que reportaba el error del contexto. La llamada al metodo `initCipher()` se realizaba desde una actividad creada como varible mediante la instanciacion 
`FingerPrintActivity activity = new FingerprintActivity()`
, `activity.initCipher()` . Al instanciar la actividad de esta forma la misma no contaba con el contexto del framework Android por lo que al querer acceder la preferencia creada anteriormente se producia un error.

La solución fue agregar un callback al llamado de `FingerprintUiHelper.onAuthenticationSucceeded()` mediante una interface que implementa la clase `FingerPrintActivity`. De esta manera la actividad puede ser notificada al momento de identificar una huella exitosamente. Asi ya no es necesaria tener una instancia de la actividad en `FingerprintUiHelper` ya que le mismo no posee un contexto dentro del Framework de Android.

Answer (score 0):

Al llamar esta linea de código :

```
 SharedPreferences _prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
```

obtienes el error:

> NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null
>   object reference

El problema es que tu clase llamada `FingerPrintActivity` no extiende de `Activity` , `AppCompatActivity` o similar.

Esta Activity debe estar registrada en el `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Si extiende de Activity.

public class FingerPrintActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = FingerPrintActivity.class.getSimpleName();


    private Cipher cipher;
    private Key key;
    private FingerprintManager.CryptoObject cryptoObject;
    private FingerprintManager fingerprintManager;
    private KeyguardManager keyguardManager;
    private Context context;
    private SharedPreferences prefs;

Comment: @Rodrigo ok y esta Activity esta registrada como Activity en tu AndroidManifest.xml ? :D

Comment: :D, igualmente había pensado en eso, pero la tengo en manifest

     <activity
            android:name=".ui.fingerprint.FingerPrintActivity"
            android:label="@string/menu_titulo_FingerPrint"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:resizeableActivity="false">
    </activity>

Comment: @Rodrigo es como si no pudiera obtener el contexto por alguna razón, 
 ¿puedes agregar toda la clase ?

Comment: agregué toda la clase modificando mi pregunta original.